# Unable to create an R Markdown file in rstudio

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio

I am using Rstudio 2022.02.0+433, with r 3.6.2. When trying to create a new rmarkdown file or knit an existing one rstudio asks me to install an updated version of 'yaml' however after I've done this and restarted r the issue still persists.

Comment: What if you update R to the latest version?

Comment: After installing/re-installing that package, did you verify that that it was updated? Check the version with `packageVersion("yaml")`. I have version 2.3.5. If you find that it didn't actually update, try using base R to install the package, then return to RStudio and validate the update.